# Get the last removed value from observable collection

Tags: c#, xamarin, observablecollection, xamarin.forms

I am new to the Microsoft world. I am developing an E-commerce app using Xamarin.Forms.
I'm binding the ListView ItemSource using **ObservableCollection**. All my data is retrieved from a local database.

```
    ObservableCollection<CatlougeData>items;
    public PlaceOrderPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        var CartList =App.Database.GetAllItems ();
        items = new ObservableCollection<CatlougeData> (CartList);
        pickedItemList.ItemsSource = items;
        lblGrandTotal.Text=App.Database.GetGrandTotal ().ToString ();

    }
```

I added a Delete context Menu in the cart ListView to remove the selected cart.

**Delete code**

```
   public void OnDeleteMenu (object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var SelectedMenu = ((MenuItem)sender);
    items.Remove ((CatlougeData)SelectedMenu.CommandParameter);
 }
```

When I remove the cart item I want to update my database. To be able to do that I want to access the recently removed collection item. I'm stuck at this stage.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Dont you have the item with you which you have already removed?

Comment: @Sanjeetharan i am removing item from collection by passing command parameter.so do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer would be to store the variable before removing it, when using your `OnDeleteMenu` method:

```
private CatlougeData LastDeletedItem { get; set;}

public void OnDeleteMenu (object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var SelectedMenu = ((MenuItem)sender);
    LastDeletedItem = (CatlougeData)SelectedMenu.CommandParameter;
    items.Remove ((CatlougeData)SelectedMenu.CommandParameter);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try hooking into the CollectionChanged event of the ObservableCollection. This then allows you to determine if an item was added or removed through the NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.

For more information, please refer to the following documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx